# Routing resources/paths with :path_prefix and :name_prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the following route definied:

```
map.resources :addresses, :path_prefix => ':site', :name_prefix => 's_'
```

I've had no problem correcting my scaffolding links for "Show" and "New". But I am getting a failure to generate error when attempting to use:

```
edit_s_address_path(address) or edit_s_address
```

rake routes shows that this is the proper path. I'm perplexed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of rails is this? and can you show some code where you are trying to ref the route from? (like a snippet of a view or controller)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you use `s_edit_address_path(address)`? According to the [Rails Guide on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), the `name_prefix` comes at the start of the route name.

Comment: That's what I thought, too. But I get an undefined method name using the name prefix at the beginning. rake routes shows that 'edit' and 'new' prefix everything.